Google Play Console: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This task listener doesn't support child surface attachment
``
There is a bug reported from by Google Play store testing (Pre launch Report) on 2 device.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This task listener doesn't support child surface attachment.
I am not able to find what is the issue. Need help in understanding and what can be done to fix that issue.

Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: This task listener doesn't supp`your text`ort child surface attachment.
  at com.android.wm.shell.ShellTaskOrganizer$TaskListener.attachChildSurfaceToTask (ShellTaskOrganizer.java:108)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.attachToParentSurface   (CompatUIWindowManager.java:190)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.attachToParentSurface     (CompatUIWindowManager.java:110)
  at android.view.WindowlessWindowManager.addToDisplay (WindowlessWindowManager.java:146)
  at android.view.WindowlessWindowManager.addToDisplayAsUser (WindowlessWindowManager.java:187)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:1149)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:1026)
  at android.view.SurfaceControlViewHost.setView (SurfaceControlViewHost.java:264)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.initCompatUi (CompatUIWindowManager.java:288)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIWindowManager.createLayout (CompatUIWindowManager.java:122)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIController.createLayout (CompatUIController.java:229)
  at com.android.wm.shell.compatui.CompatUIController.onCompatInfoChanged (CompatUIController.java:141)
  at com.android.wm.shell.ShellTaskOrganizer.notifyCompatUI (ShellTaskOrganizer.java:645)
  at com.android.wm.shell.ShellTaskOrganizer.onTaskInfoChanged (ShellTaskOrganizer.java:466)
  at android.window.TaskOrganizer$1.lambda$onTaskInfoChanged$6$TaskOrganizer$1 (TaskOrganizer.java:283)
  at android.window.TaskOrganizer$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:67)

I have tested it in multiple devices locally but am unable t reproduce the issue.
``
